# PinguyBuilder not installing on Ubuntu 20.04 because of unmet dependencies

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, dependencies, backup

I am trying to back up my distro. In the past, I have used PinguyBuilder. This was also on Linux Mint 19.3 (Ubuntu 18.04). I tried to install PinguyBuilder 5.2.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.1 as a `.deb` file. After I downloaded it, I went to open it with **Software install**. It takes a few seconds and then it says:

```
Unable to install PinguyBuilder
E: the following packages have unmet dependencies
```

I also tried this in GDebi, no positive results.

How can I fix this??

Comment: What are the unmet dependencies?

Comment: I don't know, it just says that the following packages have unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to install it with gdebian, to be more exact with:

```
sudo gdebi pinguybuilder_5.2-1_all.deb
```

(in the Downloads folder)

But it didn't work, because it had unmet dependencies, as in Software Install. It seems that PinguyBuilder needs "python-glade2" to install correctly.

Edit: Seems like that PinguyBuilder, as it is built for 18.04, uses the glade library for python-2, which is deprecated since 18.04

It is better to use the [menu-based-version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/pinguybuilder-menu-based_5.2-1_all.deb/download) of PB, as it still works in 20.04

Answer (score 1):

1. Download [`pinguybuilder_5.2-1_all.deb`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/)
2. Extract it
3. Copy files manually in their places.
4. Type `sudo PinguyBuilder-Gtk`

The "P" and "B" in PinguyBuilder are in capital letters.

Answer (score -2):

To fix the unmet dependencies error, run:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Running `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` is not a good practice since this will install all `.deb` files in the current directory (that's what `*.deb` means), which can cause issues.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Not only that, but the `dpkg` command will fail. `dpkg` is really strict with dependency problems. It partial installs the package when this happens, resulting to several more issues. Moreover, running `-f` to satisfy dependencies is strongly discouraged.